# Is it possible to make an xss with only html tags

Tags: javascript, xss, html

I'm not aware of all the xss tricks..

While programming in Ruby on Rails, using a [sanitize method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize) to allow only certain tags and it makes its best to clear all the other tags and scripts

the remaining tags are

```
    "small", "dfn", "sup", "sub", "pre", "blockquote", "ins", "ul", "var", "samp", "del",
 "h6", "h5", "h4", "h3", "h2", "h1", "span", "br", "hr", "em", "address", "img", "kbd",
 "tt", "a", "acronym", "abbr", "code", "p", "i", "b", "strong", "dd", "dt", "dl", "ol",
 "li", "div", "big", "cite"
```

Is it possible to create an XSS attack with a combination of these tags?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. It's trivial.

```
<div onmouseover="alert(1)" style="position:fixed;left:0;top:0;width:9999px;height:9999px;"></div>
```

Might want to save your work before trying that, though - the alert might show repeatedly as you move your mouse across the screen.

Of course, a better attack would involve destroying the `div` as soon as the JavaScript is called, in order to make it look legitimate.

You should escape all output in order to avoid this.

Comment: is it possible if `"` is escaped?

Comment: Yes, they can just use `'` instead. Or they could exploit unicode parsing tricks to inject a `"` or `'` character.

Comment: @Nick Ginanto yes `onmouseover=alert(1)`

Comment: Ah, yes, they could just do that instead, too.

Comment: `onmouseover` requires user interaction, `onerror` fires on pageload.

Comment: @Jacco Yup, Rook mentioned that too.

Comment: @Polynomial, yeah, I noticed two other answers mention it, but only after commenting. I was about to delete the comment, but now you already noticed.

Answer (score 14):

Yes,  almost all HTML tags allow you to declare an event handler.  Some of these events could be triggered when the page loads without user interaction:

`<img src=x onerror=alert(1) />`

Event tags are not the only way to trigger xss:

`<a href=javascript:alert(1)>xss</a>`

One possilbe solution is to set the [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives) for this page

```
X-Content-Security-Policy: unsafe-inline
```

Just make sure to actually test your solution.  Don't take anyone's word.  (Also the CSP is new)

Another option is [PHP's HTMLPurifer](http://htmlpurifier.org/) which is more advanced than Ruby's Sanitize.

Comment: is there a comparison for htmlpurifier vs ruby sanitize? how do you know it is more advanced?

Comment: @Nick Ginanto nope,  and read the docs they are very different.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: `<img onerror=alert(document.cookie) src=1 />`

The requirements for output escaping vary based on location in the document. Text that is meant to be in an HTML attribute must be escaped differently (`'"`) than text intended to be in an HTML element (`<>`), for example. The [OWASP Enterprise Security API](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Enterprise_Security_API) (ESAPI) is a good way to handle this, since it provides escaping mechanisms for all the different contexts. The Ruby version can be found [on Github](http://thesp0nge.github.com/owasp-esapi-ruby/).

Answer (score 2):

For a good 'cheat sheet' containing a number of HTML XSS attacks, see here: [OWASP.org](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet)
They get quite creative. It is worth using that sheet to test your site as it's constructed and to check back from time to time as that list is updated.

Hope it helps!